# Oscillator problem

Tags: oscillator

[image]

I was designing an oscillator for HF range. Although both the circuits are same, the first circuit doesnt work while the second one does, despite the fact that the varicap used has 17 pF at 20 V.
( Since it is my first encounter with varicap, I think I am not using it correctly)

Where am I going wrong ?

Also the output ( of the second one) is centered at around 15 V rather than 0 V. How to correct that ?

EDIT 1 :

Looks like there is a serious flaw in Multisim. I redesigned the circuits to be identical. But in Multisim, no matter what, the output is 41 KHz ( Yes, i simulated circuit 2 in multisim). I checked all the wirings etc, they are fine. LTSpice gives results close to the theorotical ones.

EDIT 2 :

I still do not understand where is the error. Here is the most recent circuit, following the suggestions :
[image]

Again here, the circuit might seem to work. But thats not the case. No matter what tuning voltage I apply, the frequency is 41 KHz. Why is that so ? Can someone help me correct this circuit ?

Comment: As well as what Andy said - Varicaps need DC bias and are AC connected.

Comment: I tried connecting the varicap supply via different resistors,as @Andy said, from 100 K ohm to 1 Meg. But the results were miles away from ideal ( 41 KHz observed). I would really appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: But you didn't note what I said. The varicaps ned DC bias. They are capacitively coupled so have no DC voltage across them. eg C14 blocks DC to D9. | Is the bottom of R2 conncted to ground as it should be? Or R1 & C6. Ground symbol looks to have "moved".

Comment: Yes, the ground is there in circuit 2 ( see the small triangle). Although I remember simulating both the circuits yesterday taking note of the suggestions, i'll try once again. It takes quite a long to simulate in multisim though. Just to be sure, I need to remove capacitor C14 and add a resistor 1 Meg or so with the battery ( circuit 1)?

Comment: I do not know what simulator you are using. I do know that in some systems (probably many (possibly most)) that if you offset a symbol as that ground symbol is that it would not be connected. Similarly R2 may not be connected.| You still to be missing what I am saying about the varicaps. There MUST be a DC circuit with the varicap in it for an applied DC voltage to work. As well as the resistor applying the +ve voltage from +20V there needs to be a **DC** path to ground on the other side. ie -> ...

Comment: ... If you applied a voltmeter across the varicap and do not see **DC** it would not be influenced by one only side being connected to DC. || 
TEST: If you place a short circuit in place of each varicap in turn, would DC current flow? If not then it is not being controlled by DC.

Comment: I am using Multisim (circuit 1) and LTSpice 4 (circuit 2).I double checked the resistors and ground. They are connected properly( circuit 2). I think what you mean is that my circuit containing the varicap and battery is not closed ( circuit 1) ? Is that so ? Since I am using a double varicap, what modification should I do then ?

Comment: Do? Exactly what I said above. See above "If you applied a voltmeter ..." and "If you place a short circuit ..." and "They are capacitively coupled so ...". Each of these describes a condition and/or something you must do and/or a test to try. What you should do is satisfy the conditions and do the test (at least in your head). If you do do the test it will fail. There will be no DC across the varicap. No DC current will flow. The varicap will not vary its cap. If you just ground the end it will kill your circuit -  so you need a DC feed at the cathode end AND at the anode end as per Andy A.

Comment: Firstly apologies for late response. There was a storm in my city and no internet. @Russell , I did exactly what you said; shorted each varicap in turn and measured DC current ( the 470 pF capacitor in series with varicap was removed). There is a DC cuurent flowing in both of them ( about 20 mA, each diode reverse biased). Also i replaced the bb204b with two MV209, but no use.

Answer (score 2):

Your first circuit won't work because you have no signal feedback to the base of Q1. Signal can't come via C8 because the other side is grounded and, signal can't come via the BB204 varactor because you have a solid 20V supply on the common pin of that device. Typically a 10k to 1M ohm resistor would be inserted in series with the 20V supply. Then it might work.

Signal feedback is needed for the circuit to oscillate and there is none!

On your 2nd circuit, C1 is not needed and can be shorted out - AC coupling will be provided via C3 and C4. This configuration will only ever have the output centred at the positive rail (+15V) because, if you analyzed it from a DC perspective, the collector is tied to +15V via the zero ohm resistance of inductor L1. If you require it to be at some other DC voltage then connect the right-hand side of C5 to that DC voltage via a 100kohm resistor and use the output from C5.

Comment: I still did not understand why my first circuit doesnt work. Can you explain a little ? As for the second question, I removed the capacitor, the output is still centered at 15 V.

Comment: I've added some text to my answer to explain - I'd missed the question about it being at 15volts.